# How to get the first, middle and last element of a list scheme and prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, scheme

I am trying to write a function in Scheme and Prolog that returns first, middle and last item of a list. E.g., `find([4,5,8,7,9],L), L = [4,8,9]`.

I came up with this piece of code for Scheme language, but I am new to Prolog and don't know much, so how I can get the same result in Prolog?

```
(define (frst L)
   (car L))

(define (last L)
   (if (null? (cdr L))
       (car L)
       (last (cdr L))))

(define (nth L x)
   (if (= x 1)
       (car L)
       (nth (cdr L) (- x 1))))

(define (firstMidLast L)
   (list (frst L)
         (nth L (ceiling (/ (length L) 2)))
         (last L)))
```

Comment: Edited as per [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: What would you get for lists with even number of items ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to do it!

- The "trick" is to *walk down* the same list at two different speeds.
- First argument indexing keeps goals `list_first_mid_last(+,?,?,?)` deterministic.

We define `list_first_mid_last/4` like this:

```
list_first_mid_last([E|Es],E,M,L) :-
    ahead_of_mid_last([E|Es],[E|Es],M,L).

ahead_of_mid_last([],[M|_],M,M).
ahead_of_mid_last([F|Fs],Es,M,L) :-
   more_ahead_of_mid_last(Fs,F,Es,M,L).

more_ahead_of_mid_last([],L,[E|_],E,L).
more_ahead_of_mid_last([F|Fs],_,Es,E,L) :-
   evenmore_ahead_of_mid_last(Fs,F,Es,E,L).

evenmore_ahead_of_mid_last([],L,[E|_],E,L).
evenmore_ahead_of_mid_last([F|Fs],_,[_|Es],M,L) :-
    more_ahead_of_mid_last(Fs,F,Es,M,L).
```

Let's run a few queries and put Prolog<sup>1</sup> and Scheme<sup>2</sup> results side-by-side!

```
%  Prolog                                     % ; Scheme
?- list_first_mid_last([1],F,M,L).            % > (firstMidLast `(1))
F = M, M = L, L = 1.                          % (1 1 1)
                                              %
?- list_first_mid_last([1,2],F,M,L).          % > (firstMidLast `(1 2))
F = M, M = 1, L = 2.                          % (1 1 2)
                                              %
?- list_first_mid_last([1,2,3],F,M,L).        % > (firstMidLast `(1 2 3))
F = 1, M = 2, L = 3.                          % (1 2 3)
                                              %
?- list_first_mid_last([1,2,3,4],F,M,L).      % > (firstMidLast `(1 2 3 4))
F = 1, M = 2, L = 4.                          % (1 2 4)
                                              %
?- list_first_mid_last([1,2,3,4,5],F,M,L).    % > (firstMidLast `(1 2 3 4 5))
F = 1, M = 3, L = 5.                          % (1 3 5)
                                              %
?- list_first_mid_last([1,2,3,4,5,6],F,M,L).  % > (firstMidLast `(1 2 3 4 5 6))
F = 1, M = 3, L = 6.                          % (1 3 6)
                                              %
?- list_first_mid_last([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],F,M,L).% > (firstMidLast `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
F = 1, M = 4, L = 7.                          % (1 4 7)
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** Using [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) version 7.3.11 (64-bit).</sup>

<sup>**Footnote 2:** Using the [scheme](/questions/tagged/scheme) interpreter [SCM](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/SCM.html) version 5e5 (64-bit).</sup>

Comment: Can't this be a teeny-weeny bit more deterministic? Or shall be expect more from indexing?

Comment: @false. Viola! erm.., voilà!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in the case that the list has even number of items you can choose one of them (in this case the first one), this procedure should work:

**Edited per comment from user 'repeat' (i am not versed on Scheme)**

```
find([First|List], [First, Middle, Last]):-
  append(_, [Last], [First|List]),
  length(List, Length),
  NLength is Length >> 1,
  nth0(NLength, [First|List], Middle).
```

The head of the clause instantiates the First item of the list, then `append/3` takes the Last item, `length/2` computes the size-1 of the list, `>>/2` will divide that size by 2, and `nth0/3` will get the Middle item.

Comment: @repeat: I improved the answer so that is returns the same items as yo tell me Scheme does for input lists of length 1 and 2.