# Prolog Finding middle element in List

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to make use of prolog predicates and find middle element of a given list. My idea was to cut first and last element of list using recursion.Unfortunately I dont know how to handle recursion call properly.

```
delete_last(L, L1) :-  
 append(L1, [_], L).
delete_first(L,L1) :-
    append([_],L1,L).
check_len(L) :-
   length(L,LEN), \+ 1 is LEN.


delete_both([],_):-
    false.
delete_both([_,_],_) :-
    false.
delete_both([X],X):-
    true, write('MidElement').

delete_both(L,L2) :-
    delete_first(LT,L2), delete_last(L,LT),check_len(LT) 
    ->write('here should be recursive call only when length is more than one').
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you support lists of all sizes (even and odd)? If so, look at the related question "How to get the first, middle and last element of a list scheme and prolog?" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112114/how-to-get-the-first-middle-and-last-element-of-a-list-scheme-and-prolog/30117040#30117040) and this answer in particular http://stackoverflow.com/a/30117040/4609915. HTH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tighten up what you have quite a bit as follows:

```
delete_last(L, L1) :-
    append(L1, [_], L).
delete_first([_|L], L).

% No need to check length of 1, since we only need to check
% if L = [X] in the caller, so we'll eliminate this predicate
%check_len(L) :-
%    length(L, 1).           % No need for an extra variable to check length is 1

% Clauses that yield false are not needed since clauses already fail if not true
% So you can just remove those
%
delete_both([X], X) :-
    write('MidElement').

% Here you need to fix the logic in your main clause
% You are deleting the first element of the list, then the last element
% from that result and checking if the length is 1.

delete_both(L, X) :-
    delete_first(L, L1),    % Remove first and last elements from L
    delete_last(L1, LT),
    (   LT = [X]            % Check for length of 1
    ->  true
    ;   delete_both(LT, X)  % otherwise, X is result of delete_both(LT, X)
    ).
```

With results:

```
| ?- delete_both([a,b,c,d,e], X).

X = c

yes
| ?- delete_both([a,b,c,d,e,f], X).

no
```

---

A DCG solution also works well here:

```
% X is the middle if it is flanked by two sequences of the same length
%
middle(X) --> seq(N), [X], seq(N).

seq(0) --> [].
seq(N) --> [_], { N #= N1 + 1 }, seq(N1).

middle(List, X) :- phrase(middle(X), List).
```

With results:

```
| ?- middle([a,b,c,d,e], X).

X = c ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?- middle(L, a).

L = [a] ? ;

L = [_,a,_] ? ;

L = [_,_,a,_,_] ?
...
```

---

Another possible solution is to use SWI Prolog's `append/2` predicate, which appends a list of lists (assuming you're using SWI):

```
middle(L, X) :-
    same_length(Left, Right),
    append([Left, [X], Right], L).

same_length([], []).
same_length([_|T1], [_|T2]) :- same_length(T1, T2).
```

---

In all of the above solutions, the predicate fails if the list has an even number of elements. Since that's what your original solution does, I assumed that's what is required. If there is a specific requirement for even lists, that needs to be stated clearly.

Answer (score 3):

It would save a lot of typing if you checked the *length* of the list, calculated the *position* of the middle element, and only then *traversed* the list to get the element at that position. With SWI-Prolog, this would be:

```
?- length(List, Len),
   divmod(Len, 2, N, 1),
   nth0(N, List, a).
List = [a],                                 Len = 1, N = 0 ;
List = [_G2371, a, _G2377],                 Len = 3, N = 1 ;
List = [_G2371, _G2374, a, _G2380, _G2383], Len = 5, N = 2 . % and so on
```

This solution makes sure the list has an odd length. You can see the [documentation of `divmod/4`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=divmod/4) if you need to define it yourself. Or, if the list does not have to have and odd, length, just use `N is Len div 2`. If for some reason you are not allowed to use `nth0/3`, it is still an easier predicate to implement than what you are trying to do.