# List operation in Prolog for deleting

Tags: prolog

There are 2 middle elements for any even-numbered list.

Help me to write a Prolog program which deletes those 2 middle elements of an even-numbered list into some other list.

Example, if we give : `?- del_mid_even([10,20,30,40,50,60],L1).`
then it will produce : `L1 = [10,20,50,60]` as output.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working with that?

Comment: @Dev: Don't forget to accept an answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64692632/8080648):

```
delete_mid2(Ori, Del):-
    delete_mid2(Ori, Ori, Del).

delete_mid2([_,_], [_,_|Slow], Slow).
delete_mid2([_,_|Fast], [H|Slow], [H|Ret]):-    
    delete_mid2(Fast, Slow, Ret).

?- delete_mid2([10,20,30,40,50,60],L).
L = [10, 20, 50, 60] ;
false.

?- delete_mid2([1,2,3,4],L).
L = [1, 4] ;
false.

?- delete_mid2([1,2,3],L).
false.

?- delete_mid2([],L).
false.
```

Comment: Nice use the tortoise and hare algorithm. :-)

Comment: credits go to TA_intern ( [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64694893/8080648)), I just learned about this.